# OSX Crashing When Connecting Multiple Bluetooth Devices

Tags: macos, mac, crash, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth keyboard ([JETech](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B0173QD5L4?tag=juil01-20&camp=8641&creative=330649&linkCode=as1&creativeASIN=B0173QD5L4&adid=1SQ0HCFY6P1A5Z08FM7Q&)) connected most of the time, and about 1/3 times when I try to connect my bluetooth speaker ([Boombot Pro](http://amzn.to/2lJjyrP)) OSX crashes and restarts.

I get this error message in the report:

`*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8012b3cb9d): "a freed zone element has been modified in zone kalloc.32: expected 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef but found 0xffffff804b69c5c0, bits changed 0x2152416f95c47b2f, at offset 16 of 32 in element 0xffffff803f7f4c00, cookies 0x3f0011a13206bfc8 0x5352135c7fcb5a3"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.41.3/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:651
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address`

For some reason it feels like a cookie problem with my browser? Is that possible?

Hoping there is some way to prevent this from happening.

**Specs:**
OSX 10.12.3
2015 13" Macbook Pro
Note: Fairly low on hard drive space (<10GB)

Comment: No, this is a completely different kind of cookie.

Comment: If your panic log contains a section called something like "Kernel loadable modules in backtrace", please edit your question to paste in that section as well. Hopefully it'll indicate which driver (called a "kernel extension" or "kext") is causing the panic. If it's a third party kext, you may be able to avoid these panics by uninstalling that kext, or checking with the vendor for an updated driver that doesn't panic.

Comment: @Spiff Looked in my Console and couldn't find this or any relevant log for some reason. Are panic logs stored somewhere else? EDIT: Never mind, found in the `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`

Comment: @Spiff In the panic log, the only instance of 'Backtrace' is the line at the end of the code I already posted and some hex values following that.